# Вложенный класс и наследование приватных переменных

Tags: c++, ооп

Почему при вложенном классе и его наследовании от класса в который он вложен наследуются приватные переменные? А также почему если убрать наследование ( `: public baseclass`), то приватные переменные продолжают отображаться в intellisense, только использовать я их не могу? Главный вопрос у меня в том как избежать этого наследования приватных переменных при том что мне нужны вложенные классы?

```
#include <iostream>

class baseclass
{
public:
    class derivedclass;
private:
    int inn = 100;
};

class baseclass::derivedclass : public baseclass
{
public:
    derivedclass()
    {
        std::cout << inn << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    baseclass::derivedclass first;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А какой вообще смысл определять производный класс как вложенный класс базового класса? Откуда базовый класс может знать, сколько у него будет производных классов, и как они будут определены? Я не вижу смысла в таком подходе.

Comment: А как они (приватные переменные) могут не наследоваться? Порождённый класс должен уметь работать вместо базового, как это сделать, не наследуя все поля?

Answer (score 3):

derivedclass не наследует приватные переменные. Т.к. derivedclass вложенный он просто видит **inn** и может использовать внутри себя. Сделайте новый класс, но не вложенный в базовый и наследуйте его и Вы увидите, что наследуется только класс derivedclass т.к. он с модификатором доступа public.